# Undefined 'StateProvider' error in Flutter with Riverpod 2.1.3

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, state-management

I'm developing a Flutter application and using the Riverpod package for state management. I encountered an issue when trying to define a StateProvider.

> The function 'StateProvider' isn't defined. Try importing the library
> that defines 'StateProvider', correcting the name to the name of an
> existing function, or defining a function named 'StateProvider'.

**Code Snippet:**

```
// final nameProvider = Provider.family<String>((ref, ) => 'caro');

 final nameProvider = StateProvider((ref)=> 'caro');

// final nameProvider = Provide<String>((ref) => 'caro');
void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using `flutter_riverpod: ^2.1.3`. I've confirmed that the import statements are correct and tried reviewing the Riverpod documentation for any changes in the `StateProvider` usage with no success.

- Has the syntax for defining a `StateProvider` changed in Riverpod 2.1.3?
- Is there an additional package or import statement I'm missing?

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no fault. I've tried your code myself.

Perhaps a simple run of the command: `flutter pub get`.

The only thing I don't know is what the third import is. I.e. `import 'package:riverpod/home_screen.dart';` as that is not part of the "real" `riverpod` package.

Comment: Hello @RobertSandberg I make a silly mistake, I named my project "riverpod" that's why I got this error on terminal `Because riverpod depends on flutter_riverpod ^2.1.3 which depends on riverpod 2.1.3, riverpod 2.1.3 is required. So, because riverpod is 1.0.0+1, version solving failed.`

Comment: @lomipac same silly mistake makes me cry...